# drupal nginx 404 error for image

Tags: nginx, drupal

I am used this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-drupal-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-13-04-vps

to install Drupal 7 on my LEMP . everything work fine.

i am using a drupal module "views infinite scroll"

this module have in image here (sites/all/modules/views_infinite_scroll/images/ajax-loader.gif)

this image not showing , show 404 error here my link: 
http://smswiki.ir/sites/all/modules/views_infinite_scroll/images/ajax-loader.gif

how can i fix this? 
i think it's have very esay solution :)

Comment: http://smswiki.ir/sites/all/modules/views_infinite_scroll/images/ajax-loader.gif
already works, the issue is resolved?

Comment: yes , i solved.